# How to spy on a method of an ES6 class with Jest and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to spy on a method of an ES6 class which I have manually mocked.

I'm following the official Jest documentation, which targets only JavaScript.

Here's my code:

```
// sound-player.ts
export default class SoundPlayer {
  foo: string

  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar'
  }

  playFile(fileName: string) {
    console.log(`Playing sound file: ${fileName}`)
  }
}
```

```
// __mocks__/sound-player.ts
export const mockPlayFile = jest.fn()

const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return { playFile: mockPlayFile }
})

export default mock
```

```
// sound-player-consumer.ts
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player'

export default class SoundPlayerConsumer {
  soundPlayer: SoundPlayer

  constructor(soundPlayer: SoundPlayer) {
    this.soundPlayer = soundPlayer
  }

  playSomethingCool() {
    this.soundPlayer.playFile('something-cool.mp3')
  }
}
```

```
// sound-player-consumer.test.ts
// @ts-ignore
import SoundPlayer, { mockPlayFile } from './sound-player'
import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer'

jest.mock('./sound-player')

const MockedSoundPlayer = SoundPlayer as jest.Mock<SoundPlayer>

beforeEach(() => {
  MockedSoundPlayer.mockClear()
  mockPlayFile.mockClear()
})

it('We can check if the consumer called the class constructor', () => {
  const soundPlayer = new MockedSoundPlayer()
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer(soundPlayer)
  expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})

it('We can check if the consumer called a method on the class instance', () => {
  const soundPlayer = new MockedSoundPlayer()
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer(soundPlayer)
  soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool()
  expect(mockPlayFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something-cool.mp3')
})
```

These tests pass, because I used a trick.

Please pay attention to the first line of `sound-player-consumer.test.ts`. Without that, the TypeScript compiler would complain about `mockPlayFile` not being exported by `sound-player.ts`.

To me, this means that from Jest's perspective everything is fine.

However, I would like to fix everything from TypeScript's perspective and remove the `@ts-ignore` comment.

Comment: Did you mean "first line of `sound-player-consumer.test.ts`"?

Comment: You _can't_ do that otherwise. The interface of the `sound-player` module (and the actual implementation, for that matter), _doesn't_ have a named `mockPlayFile` export.

Comment: @kelly, yes that's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but then how can I access the mock function? it looks like I can access it in JavaScript but not in TypeScript? I was hoping I could somehow let the compiler know about the existence of the mock function? Perhaps with a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: Generally I don't bother. I want the compiler to tell me if there's a type mismatch in my own code, I don't care about fudging a mock for something else.

Comment: What is the point of exporting `mockPlayFile`? Can't you access `soundPlayer.playFile` directly? If `soundPlayer.playFile` is private you could make a special getter for it on the `MockedSoundPlayer`.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah this is a little tricky and awkward.

```
// @ts-ignore
import SoundPlayer, { mockPlayFile } from './sound-player'
```

The reason the `@ts-ignore` comment is required here is because the types themselves are not *rewired* as a result of calling `jest.mock('./sound-player')` only the actual module values (i.e. javascript).

The reason this still works with `@ts-ignore` is because with the `mock`, importing anything from `./sound-player` is as if you were importing from `__mocks__/sound-player.ts`, minus the types.

So how to get around this? You could just import `mockPlayFile` directly from the `__mocks__` file. This will use the actual type of `mockPlayFile` alleviating the need for the `@ts-ignore`.

```
// sound-player-consumer.test.ts
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player'
import { mockPlayFile } from './__mocks__/sound-player'
import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer'

jest.mock('./sound-player')

// ...
```

Alternatively, you could also just not import `mockPlayFile` and use the class instance method instead (i.e. `soundPlayer.mockPlayFile`).

```
it('We can check if the consumer called a method on the class instance', () => {
  const soundPlayer = new MockedSoundPlayer()
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer(soundPlayer)
  soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool()
  expect(soundPlayer.mockPlayFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something-cool.mp3')
})
```

> Note this is only possible because you define `mockPlayFile` as a `jest.fn` mock outside of the class mock implementation in `__mocks__/sound-player.ts`. As opposed to defining the `jest.fn` for each call to the class mock implementation, in which case the mock function would be different.

---

### Side note

Jest permits manually mocking a class by simply exporting the mock class implementation directly, see docs example [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock-that-is-another-es6-class). In your case you could just do...

```
// __mocks__/sound-player.ts
export const mockPlayFile = jest.fn();

export default class SoundPlayer {
  foo: string = 'bar';

  constructor () {
    console.log('mocked SoundPlayer constructor');
  }

  playFile = mockPlayFile;
}
```

---

I haven't tested everything IRL but I have done something similar to this in the last couple of days.  LMK if there are issues a I can put up a working example, too bad https://codesandbox.io doesn't support `jest.mock`.